# Open ranges in Ruby using floats?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to create ranges in ruby that exclude one or both of the endpoints.  So handling the concept in mathematics of open and closed interval boundaries?

For example, can I define a range from 1.0 to 10.0 that excludes 1.0

Say (with pseudo-ruby)

```
range = [1.0...10.0)

range === 1.0
=> false

range === 10.0
=> true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can exclude rightmost element of the range with `...`. See example below

```
(1..10).to_a # an array of numbers from 1 to 10 - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

(1...10).to_a # an array of numbers from 1 to 9 - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Cheers, - I'm going to edit my question for clarity.  I'm working with Floats.

Answer (score 7):

The `Range` class in Ruby only supports closed and half-open (right-open) ranges. However, you can easily write your own.

Here's an example of a half-open range in Ruby:

```
range = 1.0...10.0

range === 1.0
# => true

range === 10.0
# => false
```

The total line count for the Ruby 1.9 compliant `Range` class in Rubinius is 238 lines of Ruby code. If you don't need your open range class to support every wrinkle, corner case, special case, idiosyncrasy, backwards-compatibility quirk and so on of the Ruby Language Specification you can get by with a lot less than that.

If you really only need to test for inclusion, then something like this should suffice:

```
class OpenRange
  attr_reader :first, :last

  def initialize(first, last, exclusion = {})
    exclusion = { first: false, last: false }.merge(exclusion)
    @first, @last, @first_exclusive, @last_exclusive = first, last, exclusion[:first], exclusion[:last]
  end

  def first_exclusive?; @first_exclusive end
  def last_exclusive?;  @last_exclusive  end

  def include?(other)
    case [first_exclusive?, last_exclusive?]
    when [true,  true]
      first <  other && other <  last
    when [true,  false]
      first <  other && other <= last
    when [false, true]
      first <= other && other <  last
    when [false, false]
      first <= other && other <= last
    end
  end

  alias_method :===, :include?

  def to_s
    "#{if first_exclusive? then '(' else '[' end}#@first...#@last#{if last_exclusive? then ')' else ']' end}"
  end

  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end
```

Comment: At first I started out to remove and minimize duplication with a nested `if`, but that one is just so much clearer, even though all the individual comparisons are duplicated. DRY is a guideline not a mantra.

Answer (score 4):

Ranges constructed using `..` run from the start to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

```
('a'..'e').to_a    #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
('a'...'e').to_a   #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

See more [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html)

You could easily write your own Range to exclude the start value too.

For float ranges:

```
(1.0..10.0).step.to_a # => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
(1.0...10.0).step.to_a # => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
(1.0..10.0).step(2.0).to_a # => [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
(1.0...10.0).step(2.0).to_a # => [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: Again, apologies.  I'm working with Floats.  Edited question to reflect that.  `range = (1.0...10.0); range === 1.0  => true`

Answer (score 0):

a few years later but...
what about taking advantage of the facts that a case statement evaluates each criteria in order of appearance and follows the path based on it's first match.
In the sample 1.0 always does nothing even though it's technically a valid value for the second "when".

```
case myvalue
    when 1.0
      #Don't do anything (or do something else)
    when 1.0...10.0
      #Do whatever you do when value is inside range 
      # not inclusive of either end point
    when 10.0
      #Do whatever when 10.0 or greater
    end
```